# Trouble uploading file with react webapp

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I am creating a React web app with an ASP.NET Core backend. For some reason, when I try to upload a file through the React web app, it doesn't want to upload and responds with a 400 Bad Request.

This is my React code:

```
const handleFileChange = async (e) => {
     const file = e.target.files[0];

     if (!file) {
         console.error("No file selected");
         return;
     }

     const deviceName = window.prompt('Please enter the device name:');

     if (!deviceName || deviceName.trim() === '') {
         alert('Device name is required.');
         return;
     }

     const dataType = window.prompt('Please enter the data type:');

     if (!dataType || dataType.trim() === '') {
         alert('Data type is required.');
         return;
     }

     const formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('file', file);
     formData.append('deviceName', deviceName);
     formData.append('dataType', dataType);

     for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
         console.log(key, value);
     }

     try {
         const response = await fetch('https://localhost:7074/MainController/uploadFile', {
             method: 'POST',
             body: formData,
             credentials: 'include'
         });
         for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
             console.log(key, value);
         }

         if (response.ok) {
             console.log('File uploaded successfully');
         } else {
             console.error('Error response:', response);
             const errorData = await response.json();
             console.error('Error data:', errorData);
             alert(`Error uploading file: ${errorData.message || 'Unknown error'}`);
         }
     } catch (error) {
         console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
         alert(`Error uploading file: ${error.message}`);
     }
};
```

ASP.NET Core `MainController` upload method:

```
[HttpPost("uploadFile")]
[RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000)]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file, string deviceName, string dataType)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"Received file: {file?.FileName}");
     Console.WriteLine($"Received deviceName: {deviceName}");
     Console.WriteLine($"Received dataType: {dataType}");

     try
     {
         DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
         var currentTime = date1.AddHours(2);

         var existingDevice = await _repository.GetDeviceByNameAsync(deviceName);

         using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
         {
             var jsonString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

             // Parse JSON using JArray 
             var jsonArray = JArray.Parse(jsonString);

             var dataSetList = new List<DataSet>();

             // Iterate over elements in the JSON array
             foreach (var jsonDocument in jsonArray)
             {
                 // Convert JSON object to dictionary
                 var properties = jsonDocument.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>();

                 // Iterate through the properties and find the first integer value
                 int value = 0;
                 foreach (var property in properties.Values)
                 {
                     if (property is int intValue)
                     {
                         value = intValue;
                         break;
                     }
                     else if (property is long longValue)
                     {
                         value = (int)longValue;
                         break;
                     }
                     else if (property is double doubleValue)
                     {
                         value = (int)doubleValue;
                         break;
                     }
                 }

                 // Create a new Data object
                 var newDataDocument = new Data
                 {
                     timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
                     value = value
                 };

                 var newDataSetDocument = new DataSet
                 {
                     deviceId = existingDevice._id,
                     timestamp = currentTime,
                     dataType = dataType,
                     Data = new List<Data> { newDataDocument }
                 };

                 // Add the new DataSet document to the list
                 dataSetList.Add(newDataSetDocument);
             }

             await _repository.InsertDataSetAsync(dataSetList);

             return Ok("File uploaded, and data added to the DataSet.");
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
         Console.WriteLine($"StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}");
         return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error. Please check server logs for more details.");
     }
}
```

This is my `program.cs`:

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using webapi.DataRepos;
//using webapi.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


// Configure MongoDB Connection
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();

var mongoDBSettingsSection = configuration.GetSection("MongoDBSettings");
var connectionString = mongoDBSettingsSection["ConnectionString"];
var databaseName = mongoDBSettingsSection["DatabaseName"];

var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase(databaseName);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>(mongoClient);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMongoDatabase>(mongoDatabase);
builder.Services.AddScoped<WebADAMDBRepo>();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "MyAllowSpecificOrigins",
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5173")
                                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                                 .AllowCredentials();
                      });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseCors("MyAllowSpecificOrigins");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And this is the error response I get in the browser console:

```
Header.jsx:68 Error response: 
Response
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 400
statusText: ""
type: "cors"
url: "https://localhost:7074/MainController/uploadFile"
[[Prototype]]: Response
```

And this is the error data:

```
Header.jsx:70 Error data: Object
errors: 
dataType: ['The dataType field is required.']
deviceName: ['The deviceName field is required.']
[[Prototype]]: Object
status: 400
title: "One or more validation errors occurred."
traceId: "00-d62c7b957ed166185afe4171bd3c8525-62ba931d7374a534-00"
type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

The values within the formData seem to be perfectly fine and align with the `POST` format in the `MainController`. I have tried uploading through Swagger and Postman and both work fine. I cannot seem to find a solution for this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the issue. It had to do with the request URL I was sending. The issue was that the backend expected the values as query parameters and not part of the request body.

```
const handleFileChange = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    if (!file) {
        console.error("No file selected");
        return;
    }

    const deviceName = window.prompt('Please enter the device name:');
    if (!deviceName || deviceName.trim() === '') {
        alert('Device name is required.');
        return;
    }

    const dataType = window.prompt('Please enter the data type:');
    if (!dataType || dataType.trim() === '') {
        alert('Data type is required.');
        return;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    // Construct the URL with query parameters
    const requestUrl = `https://localhost:7074/MainController/uploadFile?deviceName=${encodeURIComponent(deviceName)}&dataType=${encodeURIComponent(dataType)}`;

    try {
        const response = await fetch(requestUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('File uploaded successfully');
        } else {
            console.error('Error response:', response);
            const errorData = await response.json();
            console.error('Error data:', errorData);
            alert(`Error uploading file: ${errorData.message || 'Unknown error'}`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
        alert(`Error uploading file: ${error.message}`);
    }
};
```